# What does のに mean here?

Tags: particles

[羅生門](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000879/files/127_15260.html)

> 細い喉で、尖った喉仏（のどぼとけ）の動いているのが見える。その時、その喉から、鴉（からす）の啼くような声が、喘（あえ）ぎ喘ぎ、下人の耳へ伝わって来た。「この髪を抜いてな、この髪を抜いてな、鬘（かずら）にしようと思うたのじゃ。」
>
> 下人は、老婆の答が存外、平凡な**のに**失望した。そうして失望すると同時に、また前の憎悪が、冷やかな侮蔑（ぶべつ）と一しょに、心の中へはいって来た。

My [default interpretation](https://www.renshuu.org/index.php?page=grammar/individual&id=106) here would be, since 平凡 here is a na-adjective, that it would mean "despite". That is, the servant was disappointed despite the banality of her answer (that went against his expectation). The [English translation](http://www.speaking-japanese.com/breaking-index.html), however, goes:

> The servant was disappointed **by** the unexpected banality of the old woman answer.

That is, the counter-factuality of "despite" is missing.　Only causation is left. Is it due to the translator's freedom of interpretation or have I misunderstood this grammar point?

How is のに　used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 「の + に」 in two words.

It is not the 「のに」= "despite" that you thought it was.

The 「の」 nominalizes the adjective 「[平凡]{へいぼん}な」.  In meaning, 「平凡なの」＝「平凡なこと」.

「に」 is the correct particle to use in 「～～**に**[失望]{しつぼう}する」= "to be disappointed **with**"

The translator is correct.  There is no "despite" in there to begin with.